# How can i validate dto of type record in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have an endpoint to create the Seller object.I get the necessary information to create the Seller object from the dto of record type.
How can i validate this dto in spring validation? I need to make sure that the data of the incoming DTO object is validated. I don't want to validate manually.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/sellers")
public class SellerController {

    private final SellerService sellerService;
    private final CreateSellerRequestValidator createSellerRequestValidator;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody CreateSellerRequestDTO createSellerRequestDTO){
            createSellerRequestValidator.validate(createSellerRequestDTO);
            sellerService.create(createSellerRequestDTO);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```java
public record CreateSellerRequestDTO(String createdBy,
                                     String userName,
                                     String name,
                                     String email,
                                     BigDecimal shippingCost,
                                     String password,
                                     SellerAddress sellerAddress) {
}
```

Comment: Your record will need to have validation annotations, such as `@NotNull String createdBy` and then in your Controller @RequestBody `@Valid CreateSellerRequestDTO` though as this is a record, I am not quite sure if it will work.  Try and see

Answer (score 1):

***try like this:***

```
public record CreateSellerRequestDTO(@NotNull(message = "createdBy can not be null") String createdBy,
                                     @NotNull(message = "userName can not be null") String userName,
                                     String name,
                                     String email,
                                     BigDecimal shippingCost,
                                     String password,
                                     SellerAddress sellerAddress) {
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If validation annotations are not meet your requirements, you can override constructor of the record class and make your own validations. Such as

```
public record UserRecord(String name, int age, String email) {

  public UserRecord(String name, int age, String email) {
    this.name = name.trim();
    this.age = age;
    if(age > 18) {
      // email is mandatory in that case 
      this.email = email.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [compact constructor](https://medium.com/codimis/constructor-types-of-java-record-classes-19cc45050d09?sk=802c8a097984d37d7d2bbc8cd2edc124) if you don't want to handle assigning all values one by one.

You can find details [here](https://medium.com/codimis/how-to-validate-and-normalize-java-record-classes-82cae6326df8?sk=bb6ad92ff363cf60271905532360a6fe).